# Laravel: Integrating Throttle in Custom Login

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.4, throttling

How to integrate laravel throttle if I did not use the default LoginController given by laravel?

here's my controller:

```
  use AuthenticatesUsers;

  //function for login
  public function login(Request $requests){
    $username = $requests->username;
    $password = $requests->password;

    /**to login using email or username**/
    if(filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

      Auth::attempt(['email' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
    } else {

      Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
    }


    if(Auth::check()){
      if(Auth::user()->type_user == 0){

        return view('users.dashboard');

      }
      else{
        return view('admin.dashboard');
      }
    }
    else{

      return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(['message'=>$login_error],'login');

    }
  }
```

I want to limit the failed logins but I can't seem to make it work using my own controller. Can you guys help me please?

Comment: - use throttle trait as "use ThrottlesLogins;" in your login controller

Comment: still not working. :(

Answer (score 11):

add the following code inside your method. make it the first thing

```
// If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
// the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
// the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
    $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
    return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
}
```

now add the following code where log in fails. this will increment the failed attempt count.

```
$this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
```

on successful login, add the following code so it resets.

```
$this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
```

Comment: How to key this by email not username?

Comment: Override `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins::throttleKey()` method as well with your desired key.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding throttling to your controller's constructor, like so:

```
/**
 * Create a new login controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('throttle:3,1')->only('login');
}
```

Unfortunately, the Laravel docs don't say much about throttling:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#login-throttling

However, the `3,1` part of the string corresponds to a maximum of 3 tries with a decay time of 1 minute.

`throttle` could be defined in `/project-root/laravel/app/Http/Kernel.php` in the `routeMiddleware` array like so:
`'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,`.
The Laravel documentation explains this method here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Answer (score 4):

use Trait ThrottlesLogins present in Illuminate\Foundation\Auth and override the 2 functions as mentioned below. I have tested it on Laravel 5.6 and working fine.

```
public function maxAttempts()
{
    //Lock out on 5th Login Attempt
    return 5;
}

public function decayMinutes()
{
    //Lock for 1 minute
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Instead of overriding the functions you can also use properties: `protected $maxAttempts = 3; protected $decayMinutes = 1;` (either protected or public if needed)

Answer (score 2):

Although, this answer is very late, but here is , what i did, and it worked. I hope it helps you too. I am using laravel 5.2.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use Cookie;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class UserController extends Controller
{
/** Add This line on top */
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers,ThrottlesLogins;
/** This way, you can control the throttling */
protected $maxLoginAttempts=3;
protected $lockoutTime=300;

public function postUserSignIn(Request $request)
{
    /** This line should be in the start of method */
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }
    /** Validate the input */
    $validation = $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:4'
    ]);

    /** Validation is done, now login user */
    //else to user profile
    $check = Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'],'password' => $request['password']]);

    if($check){

        $user = Auth::user();
        /** Since Authentication is done, Use it here */
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        if ($user->role == 1 || $user->role == 2){
            if(Session::has('cart')){
                return redirect()->route('cart');
            }
            return redirect()->intended();
        }elseif($user->role == 99) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

    }else{
        /** Authentication Failed */
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        $errors = new MessageBag(['password' => ['Email and/or Password is invalid']]);
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($errors);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::post('login', ['before' => 'throttle:2,60', 'uses' => 'YourLoginController@Login']);
```

Comment: The throttle should be after the validation. Also there is no way to send the validation response message to the users.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return redirect()->route('login')->with('alert-warning', 'Too many login attempts');
        }

protected function hasTooManyLoginAttempts(Request $request)
{
   $maxLoginAttempts = 3;

   $lockoutTime = 1; // In minutes

   return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
       $this->throttleKey($request), $maxLoginAttempts, $lockoutTime
   );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where should I put this?

Comment: in your controller

Comment: I got an error that says: (1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method [username] does not exist.
in Controller.php (line 82)

Comment: `$this->username()` is a method in the `AuthenticatesUsers` Trait. You can browse the file at `vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php`. If you don't override it, it returns `email`.  You will get that error if you don't `use AuthenticatesUsers;` in your auth controller.

Answer (score 0):

try my version:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller{
use AuthenticatesUsers;
public function login(Request $request){
    if($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)){
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }else{
        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->login_username, 'password' => $request->login_password])) {
        session()->put(['username'=>Auth::user()->username,'userid'=>Auth::user()->id]);
        return redirect()->intended('anydashboard');
        }else{
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
            //my '/' path is the login page, with customized response msg...
            return redirect('/')->with(['illegal'=>'Login failed, please try again!'])->withInput($request->except('password'));
        }
    }
}
}
```

in order to use Eloquent Model Auth (which is default), your AUTH_MODEL should implements AuthenticatableContract, so double check your model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,CanResetPasswordContract
{
use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;
//protected $fillable = [];
...
}
```

Comment: dont think its working either. I also tried debuging `$this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);` to see if is incrementing but the result is just `null`

Comment: just take a look@ your model , like above.